# Treating initialisms as nouns

Tags: nouns, adjectives, british-english, commas, acronyms

When writing scientific articles, it is fairly common to abbreviate "randomised, controlled trial" to "RCT". Should one later refer to "a double-blind RCT" or "a double-blind, RCT"?

Is it acceptable (in UK, not USA, style writing) to treat "RCT" as the noun, and drop the comma between adjectives?

Answer (score 3):

It's acceptable in either UK or US style (and others).

Indeed, you already did that once you went so far as initialising. In initialising you're creating a word. The word is a noun. There should be no comma.

Comment: This answer seems correct, but there are no references or sources cited, could you add some?